# calling view in a new method from onCreateview in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im trying to call "view" from my inflater in my new method but it won't work, it says unresolved. if i move the whole code under setUpRecyclerView into onCreateView it works. is there a way to make it work as it is so i can keep my onCreatView tidy? all the code is in a Fragment. i alsi tried using getView.findViewById but that also didnt work.

'''

```
package com.example.hostapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference categoryref = db.collection("categories");
    private categoryCardAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);




        return view;
    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView (){
        Query query = categoryref.orderBy("name",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<categoryCard> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<categoryCard>()
                .setQuery(query, categoryCard.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new categoryCardAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

'''

this is the code that works:

```
package com.example.hostapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference categoryref = db.collection("categories");
    private categoryCardAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        Query query = categoryref.orderBy("name",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<categoryCard> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<categoryCard>()
                .setQuery(query, categoryCard.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new categoryCardAdapter(options);

        **RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);**
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView (){

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `setupRecyclerView()` method in your first code sample. You can either call it from your `createView()` method before returning the view or you can call the method from `onViewCreated()` method. I would prefer the second option.

Comment: so i called in now 
`
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        setUpRecyclerView();
        return view;
    }
`
But its view.findViewById is still not working

Comment: can you post  the changes you did ?